# Simple Python File/Object Instance

Tags: python, oop, file-io

Let's say I have the following code,

```
file1 = open("myfile","w")

#Write to file1...

#Open Second File
file2 = open("otherfile","w")

#Write to file2...

file1.close()

file1 = file2

file2.close()
```

Will this effectively result in all files being closed or will file1 still have an open file (otherfile) that can be written to still?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. (To clarify, both file objects will be closed, and will not be able to be written to)
The variable names are just references to the underlying objects. When you call the `close()` method on an object, it accesses that object and executes that method. If you examine both objects afterwards, you can tell:

```
>>> file1
<closed file 'file2.txt', mode 'w' at 0x10045e930>
>>> file2
<closed file 'file2.txt', mode 'w' at 0x10045e930>
>>>
```

Note that in this situation, you set `file1 = file2` so they both refer to the same closed file object. If there are no more references to the original `file1` object, that object will be garbage collected.

Answer (score 1):

No, by your second-last line both `file1` and `file2` refer to the same file object, which is closed by `file2.close()`. Python variables are just names pointing to objects, so what you do to one name happens to all names pointing at that object.

Answer (score 0):

since you closed file1 before you re-assigned it, both files are closed